# Plotting temporal network - TRUE/FALSE value needed for edge list

Tags: r, graph, social-networking

I am trying to start off with plotting a basic static network using the data below. 
The data represents a small cluster of an infectious disease outbreak.

```
PHStaticEdges
```

```
tail head 
1    2    
1    3    
1    4    
2    5
```

```
PHVertexAttributes
```

```
vertex.id name Place
1         A    House
2         B    House
3         C    Flight
4         D    Work
5         E    Flight
```

When I run this code:

```
thenetwork <- network(
  PHStaticEdges,
  vertex.attr = PHVertexAttributes,
  vertex.attrnames = c("vertex.id", "name", "place"),
  directed = FALSE,
  bipartite = FALSE
)
plot(thenetwork)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in if (matrix.type == "edgelist") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Ultimately I would like to create a temporal plot showing branching edges over time, but I need to get the static plot right first!
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your vertex_list had some factor ? The following code work like a charm:

```
Phedges <- data.frame(from = c(1,1,1,2) , to= c(2,3,4,5) , stringsAsFactors = F)
#don't want factor in the edges-list

phvertex <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F, 
     vertex.id = 1:5,
     name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
     type = c( 'House', 'House', 'Flight', 'Work', 'Flight')
                       )
#don't want factor in the nodes-list

thenetwork <- network::network(
   Phedges,
   vertex.attr = phvertex,
   vertex.attrnames = c("vertex.id", "name", "type"),
    directed = FALSE,
     bipartite = FALSE )

 # then you plot if you want = the network is ok
 plot(thenetwork)
 ggraph::ggraph(thenetwork) + ggraph::geom_node_point() + ggraph::geom_edge_link() + 
 ggplot2::theme_void() # assuming you have these cool packages.
```

*PS*: Good luck with `networkDynamic::activate.edges` or dynamic-nodes. *In my opinion*, play with the tidyverse and the edges-list (in order to select data and create several 'slice' of network, compute analysis and keep understanding of different 'temporal-version' of the same data). It is more easy to filtering an edges-list with the tidyverse than filtering these temporal-networks packages.

Comment: Thank you so much!! 

There weren't any factors .. which was very odd. I changed the numeric columns to character columns and it worked - not too sure why. I'll have a look with the edges list bit in tidy verse - thank you!